# how to create Rails To do list app with pre filled list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are a lot of tutorials on the internet about how to create a rails app where a user can create, edit, delete a task.

I need to create an app where there is a pre filled list of tasks with checkboxes that the user can tick off.

Being a noob to rails, I can't really find any resources to point me in the right direction.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should just add a method called `prefill_todos!` on `User`, then call that on creation. Here's a sketch of how this might look:

```
class User
  def prefill_todos!
    todos.create! name: "Buy Milk", deadline: (Date.today + 2.days)
    todos.create! name: "Use this app", complete: true
    todos.create! name: "Tell 3 others about this app", deadline: (Date.today + 1.week)
  end

  # Automatically add dummy todos after creating the object.
  # NOTE: Probably better to explicitly call user.prefill_todos! when you create user.
  after_create :prefill_todos!
end
```

Note: this answer only deals with the question of prefilling TODO items. You'll need to follow a separate tutorial (or ask a separate stack overflow question) covering that thing. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a check box with default true, you can use the following code in the migration:

```
class AddTaskToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :task, :boolean, :default => 1
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :task
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so assuming the tutorials you are referring to save the created tasks to a database then you could create your task list app by following a tutorial and then use seeds.rb to pre-seed the database with the initial set of tasks. There is a tutorial on using seeds.rb  [on railscasts here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data). It's a little dated but is still relevant to rails 3.x